# Why does this audio file work in Windows, but not Ubuntu?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, ubuntu, audio

I took the following steps in making a JAR file with the audio file I found at: http://www.orangefreesounds.com/loud-alarm-clock-sound/

1. Open Eclipse, create a new Java project.
2. Download the audio file, place it in the `src/sound-effects` folder of the project.
3. Copy and paste the code below into some class named `Sandbox`
4. In the `Project Explorer` window (probably on the left-hand side of your screen), right-click on your project and click `Export ...` as a `JAR file`
5. Run it in the terminal of a Windows or Linux system using `java -jar`.

The file structure should look like:
[image]

I have `x64 Windows 8.1` and `x64 Ubuntu 14.04` installed on my computer. My question is: **why does this JAR program work in Windows but not Ubuntu?**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Sandbox
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException,
            LineUnavailableException
    {

        URL url = Sandbox.class
                .getResource("/sound-effects/Loud-alarm-clock-sound.wav");
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
        AudioFormat af = ais.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, af);

        Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(ais);
        clip.start();
        System.out.println("Drain...");
        clip.drain();
        System.out.println("...Drained");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that I had `OpenJDK 1.7` (or `IcedTea`) installed on my Ubuntu system, and `Oracle JDK 1.8` on my Windows system. As you know, `OpenJDK` is simply an open source version of Oracle's JVM and compiler. Sadly, this means that it has a few compatibility issues, such as not being able to play certain audio files.

I simply uninstalled `OpenJDK 1.7` following the directions here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/335457/how-to-uninstall-openjdk

Then I installed `Oracle JDK 1.8` using this link:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Now my audio files are able to be played fine on both Ubuntu and Windows.